# Data not flowing from tfileinputdelimited

Tags: talend

I have a `tfileinputdelimited` in my Job. I am just trying to pass the data from this to a `tfilterrow`. The data is coming from repository i.e metadata. But only 4 rows are going to `tfilterrow` whereas attaching a `tlogrow` to `tfileinputdelimited` it is showing for a input string. I have not declared any files as string.

What might be the cause for data not flowing from `tfileinputdelimited`?

```
ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_DESC,PRICE_NUMBER,WHOLESALE_COST,DISCONTINUED_FLAG,MANUFACTURER_ID,DISTRIBUTOR_ID
1313,'Regulator System','Air Regulators',250.00,150.00,'0',100,2012
```

I declared it as Input, String, String, float, float, String, int, int.

Comment: can you add screen shot of your job?

Comment: Can you post the first 10 line of your CSV ?

Comment: Thanks for seeking question. I was not using Trim feature in tfileinputdelimited. Thats why it was not passing data :)